# How to do a sequential read in a lua table in c code

Tags: c, lua

I have a lua table that I need to read sequentially, but the reading order is completely random

**Table:**

```
    MP_STATS = {
      ENABLE = true,
      NOBLOCK = false,
      RECOVERY = false,
      EXPERIENCE = true,
      ....
    }
```

**Code example:**

```
void read_test(void){
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        ShowError("Error reading 'test.lua'\n");
        return;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "MP_STATS");   
    lua_pushnil(L);
    while (lua_next(L, 1) != 0) {
        const char *name = lua_tostring(L, 2);
        
        if(check_exist_stats(name) == 0) {
            printf("Stats %s not exist.\n", name);
            lua_pop(L, 1);
            continue;
        }
        
        lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), name);
        myvar = lua_toboolean(L, lua_gettop(L));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        printf("%s\n", name);
    }

    lua_close(L);
    printf("Read test.lua complete.\n");

}
```

When I run the program I have the following reading order

**First run:**

```
MP_NOBLOCK
MP_ENABLE
MP_EXPERIENCE
MP_RECOVERY
```

**Second run:**

```
MP_RECOVERY
MP_ENABLE
MP_NOBLOCK
MP_EXPERIENCE
```

**Third run:**

```
MP_ENABLE
MP_NOBLOCK
MP_EXPERIENCE
MP_RECOVERY
```

What should I do for reading to be done in sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Non-sequence entries of Lua tables use the hash part - that is, the order of traversal depends on the hashes of the keys; it does not depend on the order of key-value pairs in your table constructor (your code). Newer Lua versions will "randomize" hashes to mitigate hash collision attacks. This is why you get a different order each time.

The "fix" is to either:

1. Keep your current table structure, but add a second table `local order = {"ENABLE", "NOBLOCK", "EXPERIENCE", "RECOVERY", ...}` to remember the order of the keys. Then loop over this second table, which uses the "array part" *in order* using `ipairs` and use the values as keys for your current table structure.
2. Switch to a "list" for your `MP_STATS` table and use said `order` table to look up keys for given indices.
3. Switch to a "list" of "pairs" `{key = "...", value = "..."}` which can be iterated in-order using `ipairs`.

Comment: In the lua code I know that it is used that way, I want to know in the C Code what should I do

Comment: @albertosilva in the C code you can have an `order` "array" just as well.

Comment: How to do this ? Could you explain me ?

Answer (score 1):

Tables are associative arrays. Depending on the implementation, they may or may not provide a consistent ordering.

So does Lua use an implementation that returns a consistent ordering? As you already discovered, no. "The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even for numeric indices", says the documentation for `next`.

Lua does not provide the elements in the (unspecified) order you desire, because it returns the elements in an arbitrary order.

---

Note that the order isn't random, merely arbitrary.

Comment: In lua in c code there is no way to make a sequence?

Comment: In practice it is "random" across runs due to the randomized seeds of the hashes.

Comment: What do you mean by "sequence"? Ordered list of items? One would use an array for that. In Lua, an array is obtained by using an array-like table and `ipairs`

Comment: @LMD, Depends on the implementation. There's no guarantee that a hash is used, much less one with randomized seeds. And even in that situation, the order would still be arbitrary, not random, as insertion order does affect iteration order.

Comment: @ikegami in practice the insertion order will be the same here since a table constructor is used. Of course you can't in any way rely on it being (seemingly) "random" across runs. "Arbitrary" is indeed the better word here, but I think it's important to explain why it is "non-deterministic" now; it used to be constant on older PUC Lua interpreters.